# handling file uploads sent via xhr using play framework v2.4

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, playframework-2.0, asyncfileupload, angular-file-upload

I am using play framework v2.4 and am testing file uploads sent via a web form (xhr call via angular).  I have tried the following two options in the play framework controller (based on https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaFileUpload) but neither option works (I also added the curl sample I tried but I am unable to get a reference to the file - its always null).  The MultipartFormData/File is null in either case.
Thanks

```
MultipartFormData body = request().body().asMultipartFormData();
```

or

```
File file = request().body().asRaw().asFile();
```

The curl command I am using is as follows (I can see the file data being sent from curl):

```
curl -v --cookie "Auth-Token=dc6eb764-4436-4571-b4bf-8cf5dg36b71b" -F "doc=@/home/test/docs/books/play2.pdf" https://local.test.com/a/api/contact/abc/test
```

Comment: issue was with the client upload in JS - the file was never making it to the server.  Fixing the curl command allowed me to test the file upload on the server

Comment: Ali, could you perhaps post how you debugged it as part of an answer to your own question (rather than just a comment)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue was with the client side JS code that was not uploading the file.  The following worked:

```
MultipartFormData body = request().body().asMultipartFormData();
```

**test with curl**

```
curl -v --cookie "Auth-Token=dc6eb764-4436-4571-b4bf-8cf5dg36b71b" -F "doc=@/home/test/docs/books/play2.pdf" https://local.test.com/a/api/contact/abc/test
```